# IntegrityError Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Создаю верификацию юзеров. В форме должны быть только два поля с фото. Юзер подтягивается автоматически, коммент задаётся в админке.
При сохранении формы вылетает ошибка.
IntegrityError at /identification/

`ОШИБКА:  нулевое значение в столбце "user_id" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
DETAIL:  Ошибочная строка содержит (11, accounts/request_user/images/4c2c3ea4-a806-4964-9f1e-2e90dc91deb..., abc/Снимок_экрана_от_2019-02-21_15-10-05_LsQ3IE4.p..., , f, 2019-03-06 13:21:09.453797+00, null, 2019-03-06 13:21:09.453831+00).`

**models**

```
class RequestUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    main_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="abc")
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('created at'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_('updated at'), auto_now=True)

    @property
    def upload_dir(self):
        return 'accounts/request_user/images'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

**forms**

```
class IdentificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestUser
        fields = ('user', 'main_photo', 'profile_photo', 'comment')

    comment = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    user = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
```

**views**

```
def verification_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IdentificationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            main_photo = form.cleaned_data['main_photo']
            user = request.user
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            profile_photo = form.cleaned_data['profile_photo']
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('image upload success')
    else:
        form = IdentificationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/identification.html', {'form': form})
```

**template**

```
<form action="" class="edit_form new_event" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    {{error}}
                {% endfor %}
                {{ form.user }}
                {{ form.comment }}
                {{ form.main_photo }}
                {{ form.profile_photo }}
              <input type="submit" class="submit mgln" value="Послать запрос">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**forms**

```
class IdentificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestUser
        fields = ('main_photo', 'profile_photo')
```

**views**

```
@login_required
def verification_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IdentificationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponse('image upload success')
    else:
        form = IdentificationForm()
return render(request, 'accounts/identification.html', {'form': form})
```

**template**

```
<form action="" class="edit_form new_event" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" class="submit mgln" value="Послать запрос">
</form>
```

P.S. У вас потом вылезет ещё проблема с тем, что `RequestUser` для каждого юзера может быть только один, а при сохранении формы каждый раз создаётся новый. Но это уже тема отдельного вопроса.

Comment: не поверите, но только что также решил, благодаря `commit=False`. Поспешил с публикацей)